# JSON and Python

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json

I am developing a web interface for Arduino, using Python. For automatic updates and display, I use JSON. I have a very interesting problem.

The following code sends the command to a python function, if a command exists. Then, whether a command was sent to the function or not, the function checks for updates from the Arduino by calling another function.

Here is what I can't find any explanation to: in the first and only condition of the update() function, if I remove the line that says alert('hey'); the python function is not called anymore. But if I do write alert('hey'); after the JSON request, it works fine, the function is called and the arduino gets the message.

Anyone has an idea why?

```
function update(command=0) {

    // if a command is passed, send it

    if (command!=0) {
        $.getJSON('/action?command='+command);
        alert('hey'); // if I remove this, the action function is not called. Why?
    }

    // read from the read function, no matter what

    $.getJSON('/read', {}, function(data) {
        if (data.state != 'failure' && data.content != '') {
            $('.notice').text(data.content);
            $('.notice').hide().fadeIn('slow');
            setTimeout(function () { $('.notice').fadeOut(1000); }, 1500);
        }
        setTimeout(update, 5000); // next update in 5 secs
    });
}

update(); // for the first call on page load
```

Comment: I guess you *do* call `update` with a non-zero command somewhere?

Comment: nope, that's all the JS coe I have. I think, as Jeremy said, that the alert creates some sort of delay, but even when I use a setTimeout the function is not called, so I don't understand. And even supposing it creates a delay, why does it need one? I don't understand.

Comment: Any idea? I've tried so many ways to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking for the results of the first command with the second? If so, I suspect the **alert('hey')** is pausing execution long enough for the first to finish. Can you try making your read a callback function of the first **getJSON**?

```
function update(command=0) {

    if (command!=0) {
        $.getJSON('/action?command='+command, function() {
            read();
        });
    } else {
        read();
    }
}

function read() {
    $.getJSON('/read', {}, function(data) {
        if (data.state != 'failure' && data.content != '') {
            $('.notice').text(data.content);
            $('.notice').hide().fadeIn('slow');
            setTimeout(function () { $('.notice').fadeOut(1000); }, 1500);
        }
        setTimeout(update, 5000); // next update in 5 secs
    });
}

update(); // for the first call on page load
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SJkvf/)

Comment: The read function doesn't take any argument, so it doesn't check the first command. How to make a callback of the first getJSON with the read function? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I really don't see what is happening. How should I make a callback?

Comment: So I've checked the value of the command variable between the if and the getJSON, and it's actually reseted, I guess because the update function is called before the end of the process. How can I fix that? I've tried setting a timeout, no effect. Any ideas?

Comment: You are using a callback in your second getJSON function. I've written up a quick example. http://jsfiddle.net/SJkvf/

Comment: Thank you for your help, much appreciated, but still doesn't work. The function is not called, the command variable is reseted somehow, because of the page reload I would guess. But even adding a timeout doesn't change anything, that's what's driving me nuts.